rio.to_raster returns ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
Maybe this is more like a Pandas question but when I try to write an xarray to a raster using rio.to_raster() I get a ValueError in Python. If I don't convert the type of xarray to int16 (this is a requirement) and leave it to float64, it is working. Quite strange, if I count the NAs before writing the raster, I get 0. So I don't know what is trying to convert. The code is below:
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate random points
n_points = 10000
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = -180, -90, 180, 90

points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(
    np.random.uniform(xmin, xmax, n_points),
    np.random.uniform(ymin, ymax, n_points)
))

# Generate dummy column
dummy_data = np.random.randint(0, 100, n_points)
points['some_value'] = dummy_data

# Create a GeoCube
grid = make_geocube(vector_data=points, measurements=['some_value'], resolution=(1, 1))
grid = grid.fillna(-9999) # fill NAs

# Convert dtype to `int16`
grid['some_value'] = grid['some_value'].astype('int16')

grid['some_value'].plot()
grid['some_value'].isnull().sum() # returns 0 values

# please adjust the output location below
output_file = 'C:/Users/Desktop/exports/dummy.tif' 

grid.rio.to_raster(output_file, nodata = -9999)


Adjust this line in your code and it works
grid = make_geocube(vector_data=points, measurements=['some_value'], resolution=(1, 1), fill = -9999)
Reason being that nodata management is still a bit clunky with xarray and needs different consideration compared to how it works with .tiffs for example. You can read more in the Rioxarray documentation which I believe is what geocube uses.
